# Why does my function output numbers separated by a hyphen?

Tags: javascript, canvas

For a data visualisation project, I use JavaScript to create an interactive `canvas`. While trying to create a dot that follows the graph (see also the **(*)**-marked question), a verification of the coordinates of the dot by means of a `console.log` statement, the code outputs (for example) the following (combination of) number(s):

```
745116846.3636364-1864911.33333333335124
```

while I just want one number. Why does the `-` show up?

I can paste the code in here as well but it is quite long. If you have any suspicions regarding this mysterious sign but need code to justify your suspicions, I'll post it if you want to.

**(*)** As an aside: are there any tutorials available on creating such a dot (that follows the graph) ?

Comment: It usually happens when things you add together are strings instead of numbers (`"1.2" + "-3.4"`).

Comment: Coordinates are, by definition, a pair of values. Why are you expecting just one? Let's see the log statement.

Comment: Can you post a simplified version of the code that demonstrates the problem, and make a jsfiddle out of it? Otherwise we're just making wild guesses of what you're doing wrong.

Comment: @isherwood It's only the y-coordinate I'm printing now. To the rest: I think Juhana is right. I'm using data that is in a "text area" format. The numbers are within quotes, so I think they're actually strings.